# canvas-images (securityError)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

this is barfly,
I have a problem with canvaced-images. (securityError)
I built a tool for designing visitcards. Here I use several canvases for text and one for a logo. Without inserting an image for the logo, everything works fine. But when I insert an image I get the securityError. (In the beginning it also worked and I simply can`t figure out, which changes lead to that problem). Now I tried to make a html2canvas before sending them via ajax to a php-file. But still the same problem. It's working without the logo and throws a securityError when a logo is inserted. This is confusing me most. 
I set the whole thing on my server. The Url is: http://obs-design.de/visitenkarten/
to add an image, dobleclick any of the text-canvaces an click on the image-icon on the editor.
After proceeding, the html2canvas is shown under the original app. (here still with images). The uploaded imagefile can be called at: http://obs-design.de/visitenkarten/canvasimg/visitenkarte.png (only al long there is no image included).
Does anyone have a hint for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At first, you could fly to [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  page ...

Comment: hi @barfly, nice to meet you! :) ... please include the security error statement.

Comment: the error statement was: [link] SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
error source line:
 

var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");   But with help of Kaiido I was able to fix that and now everything works fine. Anyway thanks a lot for your interest. barfly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are calling `html2canvas()` on your body element.

Your document does contain a reference to `https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png` which is not loaded with proper CORS header.

The simple fix is to call html2canvas on your `#innerbox` element.
In this part of the document, there is nothing that will taint your canvas and you'll be able to call any export method as you wish.

Also note that canvas element doesn't have a `crossOrigin` attribute, media-resources drawn to its context must have been served with proper cross-origin requests, you can't do that at the canvas level.

Comment: Thanks a lot für your help. Now everything works fine.

Comment: Hi Kaido - First I thougt everything is ok but it isn't. Like before it sometimes worked and than it failed again. I can't understand the difference betwenn a canvas (that was made by html2canvas) with and without an image Where is the difference between those 2 canvases. I included the the crossOrigin in the header like so: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/visitenkarten.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>. Is this correct sofar? Where and how do I include the CORS header? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The cors header is sent by the server that hosts the media you will draw on your canvas. If the server is not configured to accept crossOrigin requests, you're out of luck. You have to set the crossIrigin attribute on the img tag before setting its src so tha the server knows you want to comply with cors.

Comment: Ok what I found out now is, that when I insert a picture and resize it thatway that the icon is no longer visible, it works. Only when inserting little images it fails. So it seems, that you where right with your hint concerning that icon. Now I try to make the icon unvisible before making the html2canvas. (like I do with the button (var but = document.getElementById('button');
 but.style.display='none';). But whatever I tried, I just get it.  document.getElementByClassName, by tag-name and.. and ..and. nothing works. Could you give me a last hint for this. Sorry for nerving you ;-)

Comment: OK, I got it now. Like you said in your first post, It really was the icon that was responible for that error. I changed the jqery.css and made that icon visible only on :hover-state. Is there any opportunity to give you a good rating for your help? As far as I understood the 'How to'-Page I cant do any ratings because I don't have enough points myself. This seems some kind of mysterious to me. If I misunderstood the how-to-page, please let me know. I really would like do thank you for your time and your help although you allready have a very good rating. CU - barfly

Comment: @barfly, you already accepted my answer, giving me 15 unicorm points. When you'll yourself reach a certain threshold (I don't remember, maybe 10 or 20), you'll be able to upvote answers you find valuable. But until then you'll have to provide good contents to be able to reach this threshold, and you will probably have forgotten about me at this time. Which is just fair. I'm glad it helped you, I hope it will help someone else, that's it. I don't really care about UP.